# driver for dashcam

Tags: drivers, webcam

I have a MiOS dashcam that was once working on an ancient Windows 7 machine. I'd like to use it on my ubuntu. The two model/serial numbers I can see are 84202202 and 260167. I'd like help finding driver software.

[image]

Comment: Quick google search returned no results. If you could give a model name for the camera that would be beneficial. ***That being said,*** the fact that it worked on an "ancient" Windows 7 machine means most likely the drivers have not been updated since new hardware has come along, and even if there are Windows drivers for this camera, that does not mean that there will be Linux drivers. ***TLDR;*** if you can, find a model name, however I have very little hope that a driver will exist

Comment: In a terminal window, type `sudo journalctl -f`, then plug in your camera. When you have seen enugh, type `^C` to exit. Also `lsusb` (when it's plugged in).

Comment: @waltinator  I see ) event19 - Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera (Venu: device is a keyboard
  : Invalid usb_open: Permission denied - so I guess this is hopeless. Disappointing but not a real barrier to what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question so that it does not continue to attract attention.

Comments from @David and @waitinator convincingly argue that my quest is hopeless.